# How can I run a javafx application in full screen on a raspberry pi?

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi3, openjfx

I am trying to find out how to run a JavaFX (13) application on a raspberry pi 3 in fullscreen. My project is made on windows with gradle, and it works fine there, but I have not been able to run the application at all. I have openjdk13 (arm32) installed and it just gives me errors about using 64 bit javafx, which I can not seem to fix. The error code is ELFCLASS64. I am wondering if there is a way to make it run on raspbian, or if I need to find a 64 bit operating system of some kind. If anyone has a suggestion for a linux distro for this, please tell me. I am not very experienced at this kind of thing, and I have not been able to find any answers on google, please help.

My build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.12.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    version = "13"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

mainClassName = "$moduleName/com.testing.MainApp"

jlink {
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'mea'
    }
}
```

My module-info.java file:

```
module mea {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens com.testing to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.testing;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using JavaFX artifacts for Linux (x86_64). That won't work on ARM (arm64). You can use [JavaFX armv6hf SDK](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/), and set `sdk` in the javafx plugin.